# Can't install yeoman because "Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH"

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

So I am trying to install yeoman but it gives me this:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
/Users/X/.npm-global/bin/yo -> /Users/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
/Users/X/.npm-global/bin/yo-complete -> /Users/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js

> yo@3.1.1 postinstall /Users/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ Node.js version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}
✖ yo version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}
✔ npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@3.1.1
+ generator-code@1.2.19
updated 2 packages in 23.236s
NOHpc02:~ William$ npm cache clean -f
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
NOHpc02:~ William$ sudo npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
/Users/William/.npm-global/bin/yo -> /Users/William/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
/Users/William/.npm-global/bin/yo-complete -> /Users/William/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js

> yo@3.1.1 postinstall /Users/William/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor


Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ Node.js version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}
✖ yo version
Error: Couldn't find the 'yo' binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yo',
  path: 'yo',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
  cmd: 'yo --version'
}
✔ npm version

Found potential issues on your machine :(
+ yo@3.1.1
updated 1 package in 30.313s
```

I have searched and searched, but none of the answers given to the same question by others worked for me.

- I have done `npm install -g yeoman-doctor`. didn't work.
- I have tried running `sudo npm install -g yo generator-code`. didn't work.
- I have tried creating the yo binary manually, couldn't find any information on how to do so.

My java is up to date, as well as my node.js. I am running MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `yarn global add yo` try using this/

Comment: Did you tried "npm install -g yo" first?

Comment: @mthkhaled yes. I finally managed to do it by changing directory to the binary forder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure version node and yo are compatible?

Before install yo I use nodejs v14.19.0 and npm v6.14.16., Then I found a problem same to you. And I have tried running **`npm install -g yeoman-doctor`** didn't work.
and  **`sudo npm install -g yo generator-code`** OK. ---> yo v4.3.0